# Delegate methods to the result of a method

Tags: ruby

First of all, this is really just a golf question. My code works fine as it is. But I feel like there is probably a better (i.e. cooler) way to do this.

So I've got a class that acts a lot like a hash. However, it really internally generates a hash for each call to its hash-ish methods. The private method for generating that hash is `calculated()`. So my code currently has a lot of method definitions like this:

```
def each(&block)
    return calculated.each(&block)
end

def length()
    return calculated.length
end
```

Is there a concise way to delegate all those method calls to the `calculated` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and it's incredibly simple. Just delegate to the name of the method. Here's a working example:

```
class MyClass
    extend Forwardable
    delegate %w([] []=) => :build_hash
    
    def build_hash
        return {'a'=>1}
    end
end
```

Comment: According to the question the method is `calculated`, not `build_hash`. Also note that when returning a new hash every time, changes via `[]=` won’t persist.

Comment: You're right, I didn't keep the name of the method consistent between question and answer. As for []=, you're also right, but in my case []= doesn't need to work. The real world situation is that it doesn't return a hash, just an object that responds to [].

Answer (score 0):

**edit: don't do this; I forgot `Forwardable` existed**

You can write a "macro" for this. Well, Ruby doesn't technically have actual "macros" but it's a fairly common pattern nonetheless. Rails in particular uses it extensively - stuff like `belongs_to`, `validates`, etc are all class methods which are being used to generate instance-level functionality.

```
module DelegateToFunc
  def delegate_to_func(delegate, delegators)
    delegators.each do |func_name|
      # Note: in Ruby 2.7 you can use |...| instead of |*args, &blk|
      define_method(func_name) do |*args, &blk|
        send(delegate).send(func_name, *args, &blk)
      end
    end
  end
end

class SequenceBuilder
  extend DelegateToFunc

  delegate_to_func(:calculated, [:length, :each])

  attr_accessor :min, :max

  def initialize(min:, max:)
    @min, @max = min, max
  end

  def calculated
    min.upto(max).to_a
  end
end

SequenceBuilder.new(min: 5, max: 10).length # => 6
SequenceBuilder.new(min: 1, max: 4).each { |num| print num } # => 1234
```

I will say, though, that methods generated by metaprogramming can sometimes be hard to track down and can make a program confusing, so try and use them tastefully ...

For example, do you really need *your object* to expose these hash-like methods? Why not just let the caller read the hash via `calculated`, and then call the hash methods directly on that?

Comment: Hm, that looks a bit complicated. It's more code than if I just created all the methods manually. But interesting stuff!

As for letting the caller just get to the calculated hash... the object object that generates that hash doesn't do anything except work with that hash, do making the caller call the calculated method every time feels redundant.

Comment: Yah @tscheingeld .... don't do this. Use the `Forwardable` approach instead. I forgot it existed but I'll leave this up as an example of how to how to do it from scratch, for reference. You can feel free to accept your own answer.